# How do you interpolate from an array containing datetime objects?

Tags: python, arrays, datetime, numpy

I'm looking for a function analogous to `np.interp` that can work with `datetime` objects.

For example:

```
import datetime, numpy as np
arr1 = np.array([datetime.datetime(2008,1,d) for d in range(1,10)])
arr2 = np.arange(1,10)

np.interp(datetime.datetime(2008,1,5,12),arr1,arr2)
```

would ideally return `5.5`, but `numpy` raises `TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type`. Is there a nice pythonic way around this?

Comment: what timezone is used? Is it local time or UTC? Local time is not monotonous and it may be ambiguous e.g., during end-of-DST transitions.

Comment: The specific application I'm interested in is satellite data, so UTC.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can convert them to timestamps (edited to reflect the use of `calendar.timegm` to avoid timezone-related pitfalls).

```
# Python 2.7
import datetime, numpy as np
import calendar

def toTimestamp(d):
  return calendar.timegm(d.timetuple())

arr1 = np.array([toTimestamp(datetime.datetime(2008,1,d)) for d in range(1,10)]) 
arr2 = np.arange(1,10)

result = np.interp(toTimestamp(datetime.datetime(2008,1,5,12)),arr1,arr2)
print result # Prints 5.5
```

Comment: `mktime()` assumes that `d` is a local time. [mktime() may fail to get the correct timestamp](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279). OP should work with UTC or aware datetime objects.

Comment: [OP input is UTC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926669/how-do-you-interpolate-from-an-array-containing-datetime-objects/27939981#comment44274845_27926669). It is incorrect to use `time.mktime()` unless the local timezone is UTC, use `calendar.timegm()` instead. [More options](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8778548/4279).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Well-spotted as always, the answer has been updated to use `calendar.timegm` instead.

Comment: @rchang I am having a smiliar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40412863/interpolation-of-a-value-with-a-corresponding-timestamp), could you please help me?

Answer (score 3):

[`numpy.interp()` function](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) expects that `arr1` and `arr2` are 1D sequences of floats i.e., you should convert the sequence of `datetime` objects to 1D sequence of floats if you want to use `np.interp()`.

If input data uses the same UTC offset for all datetime objects then you could get a float by subtracting a reference date from all values. It is true if [your input is UTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27926669/how-do-you-interpolate-from-an-array-containing-datetime-objects?noredirect=1#comment44274845_27926669) (the offset is always zero):

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([datetime(2008, 1, d) for d in range(1, 10)])
arr2 = np.arange(1, 10)

def to_float(d, epoch=arr1[0]):
    return (d - epoch).total_seconds()

f = np.interp(to_float(datetime(2008,1,5,12)), map(to_float, arr1), arr2)
print f # -> 5.5
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm providing this as a complement to @rchang's answer for those wanting to do this all in Pandas.  This function takes a pandas series containing dates and returns a new series with the values converted to 'number of days' after a specified date.

```
def convert_dates_to_days(dates, start_date=None, name='Day'):
    """Converts a series of dates to a series of float values that
    represent days since start_date.
    """

    if start_date:
        ts0 = pd.Timestamp(start_date).timestamp()
    else:
        ts0 = 0

    return ((dates.apply(pd.Timestamp.timestamp) - 
            ts0)/(24*3600)).rename(name)
```

Not sure it will work with times or if it is immune to the time-zone pitfalls mentioned above.  But I think as long as you provide a start date in the same time zone, which is subtracted from all the timestamp values, you should be okay.

Here's how I used it:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date': pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-22', freq='7D'),
    'Value': np.random.randn(4)
})

x = convert_dates_to_days(data.Date, start_date='2018-01-01')
y = data.Value
f2 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

all_dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-01-01', '2018-01-22'))
x_all = convert_dates_to_days(all_dates, start_date='2018-01-01')

plt.plot(all_dates, f2(x_all), '-')
data.set_index('Date')['Value'].plot(style='o')
plt.grid()
plt.savefig("interp_demo.png")
plt.show()
```

It seems to work...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you have/need sub-second precision in your timestamps, here's a slightly edited version of [rchang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4289293/rchang)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27926860) (basically just a different `toTimestamp` method)

```
import datetime, numpy as np

def toTimestamp(d):
  return d.timestamp()

arr1 = np.array([toTimestamp(datetime.datetime(2000,1,2,3,4,5) + datetime.timedelta(0,d)) for d in np.linspace(0,1,9)]) 
arr2 = np.arange(1,10) # 1, 2, ..., 9

result = np.interp(toTimestamp(datetime.datetime(2000,1,2,3,4,5,678901)),arr1,arr2)
print(result) # Prints 6.431207656860352
```

I can't say anything about timezone issues, as I haven't tested this with other timezones.