# Python doesn't compare date?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, compare

I have this launch_time:

> 2015-01-15 10:31:54+00:00

I get current_time

```
current_time = datetime.datetime.now(launch_time.tzinfo)
```

I want both of times are same so I used tzinfo. So, the value of current_time is

> 2015-01-16 10:55:50.200571+00:00

I take the running time with this:

```
running_time = (current_time - launch_time).seconds/60
```

The value return only **23 minutes**. It should be **one day + 23 minutes = 1463 minutes**

Can someone help me. Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are ignoring the *`.days`* attribute of the returned `timedelta` object. Use [`timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds) instead to include those in one value:

```
running_time = (current_time - launch_time).total_seconds()/60
```

or explicitly use it if you want to ignore the microseconds portion of the delta:

```
running_time = current_time - launch_time.total_seconds()
running_time = running_time.seconds / 60 + running_time.days / 1440
```

From the [documentation for `timedelta.total_seconds()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta.total_seconds):

> Return the total number of seconds contained in the duration. Equivalent to `(td.microseconds + (td.seconds + td.days * 24 * 3600) * 10**6) / 10**6` computed with true division enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Beware, `launch_time` and `current_time` may have *different* UTC offsets i.e., unless `launch_time.tzinfo` is an instance of `pytz` timezone (that stores historical (past/future) tz data) then your code is wrong. Convert `launch_time` to UTC first instead:

```
from datetime import datetime

launch_time_in_utc = launch_time.replace(tzinfo=None) - launch_time.utcoffset()
elapsed = (datetime.utcnow() - launch_time_in_utc)
```

where `elapsed` is the elapsed time since the launch time expressed as `timedelta` object.

To convert `timedelta` object to minutes in Python 3.2+:

```
from datetime import timedelta

elapsed_minutes = elapsed // timedelta(minutes=1)
```

On older Python versions you could use `.total_seconds()` as [@Martijn Pieters suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27982748/4279):

```
elapsed_minutes = elapsed.total_seconds() // 60
```

Note: `//` uses an integer division.

See also, [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).