# Datetime Delta - Extract the seconds from output (Python)

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have this small piece of code that keeps track of the runtime of a script:

```
startTime = datetime.now()
time = datetime.now() - startTime
return time
```

The type of "time" is "datetime.timedelta" and the output is "0:00:13.084000". I'm interested only in the seconds (13).

How can I extract that piece of information?

Comment: what language is this? Edit: Guessing python, but correct it if I am wrong ;p

Comment: `return time.second` will get your job done,

Comment: @Anmol_uppal Unfortunately, it doesn't :(

Comment: The correct syntax is "seconds" (with an s at the end). It works now.

Comment: do not subtruct naive datetime objects that represent local time. Local time is  not linear or even monotonous. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your object is a `datetime.timedelta` instance, so use `time.seconds` for the **seconds field only**, or `time.total_seconds()` for all the time duration, converted to seconds (They're different things)