# Python creating date objects to filter certain dates

Tags: python, parsing, datetime

I am reading different log files with different date formats. I am using python to read in the files line by line and then parse the line. I want to parse the line for dates and then formulate them into a date object to do comparisons on.

For example, say that I have 2 log files both with different date formats. How do I read them into an object to compare them to a known date. Assume for example, I wanted to discard all dates before a certain time.

Let's assume the first log file just has one line:

```
invalid access 2015-01-04 14:23:15 on IP 5.5.5.5
```

How do I read in `2015-01-04 14:23:15` into a dateobject (so I can do comparisons)

What if the date format was different? How would I read in that?

Comment: if the time string represents local time then you need to convert it to UTC or POSIX time to do comparisons because local time is non-monotonous. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279)

Comment: related: [How to parse ISO formatted date in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/127803/4279)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `datetime.datetime.strptime`:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime
In [2]: d = '2015-01-04 14:23:15'
In [3]: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 4, 14, 23, 15)
```

For other formats, check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

Answer (score 0):

dateutil can usually parse whatever

```
import dateutil.parser as p
print p.parse("2015-01-04 14:23:15")
```

this assumes you can isolate your datestring

```
$ easy_install python-dateutil 
$ pip install python-dateutil
```

or simply attainable at https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.4.0 if you need the source ...

Comment: A link to [`dateutil`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil/2.4.0) might be helpful as it isn't in the stdlib.

Answer (score 0):

Using `re` module directly might be more efficient than using it implicitly via `datetime.strptime()` (measure it to find out whether it matters in your case):

```
>>> import datetime, re   
>>> s = '2015-01-04 14:23:15'
>>> datetime.datetime(*map(int, re.findall('\d+', s)))
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 4, 14, 23, 15)
```