# How do I construct a UTC `datetime` object in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone

I am using [the `datetime.datetime` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) from the Python standard library. I wish to construct an instance of this class with the UTC timezone. To do so, I gather that I need to pass as the `tzinfo` argument to the `datetime` constructor some instance of [the `tzinfo` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo).

[The documentation for the `tzinfo` class](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#tzinfo-objects) says that:

> `tzinfo` is an abstract base class, meaning that this class should not be instantiated directly. You need to derive a concrete subclass, and (at least) supply implementations of the standard `tzinfo` methods needed by the `datetime` methods you use. The `datetime` module does not supply any concrete subclasses of `tzinfo`.

Now I'm stumped. All I want to do is represent "UTC". I should be able to do that using approximately three characters, like this

```
import timezones
...
t = datetime(2015, 2, 1, 15, 16, 17, 345, timezones.UTC)
```

In short, I'm not going to do what the documentation tells me to do. So what's my alternative?

Comment: why do not use in `pytz` - http://pytz.sourceforge.net/? Or you want to create your own objects?

Comment: @sKwa because I hadn't heard of it -- thanks! It looks like exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. But if you are interested how it works (`tzinfo`) you can read here - http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/02/understanding-datetime-tzinfo-timedelta-amp-timezo/

Comment: Thanks. By the way, if you convert your comment to an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

There are fixed-offset timezones in the stdlib since Python 3.2:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

t = datetime(2015, 2, 1, 15, 16, 17, 345, tzinfo=timezone.utc)
```

Constructor is :

```
datetime(year, month, day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0, microsecond=0, tzinfo=None, *, fold=0)
```

Docs [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects).

Though it is easy to implement utc timezone on earlier versions:

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

ZERO = timedelta(0)

class UTCtzinfo(tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO

utc = UTCtzinfo()
t = datetime(2015, 2, 1, 15, 16, 17, 345, tzinfo=utc)
```

Comment: Aha, thanks! I'm using Python 3.4; my bad for reading the python 3 documentation ...

Answer (score 4):

I used a lot in [pytz](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytz) and very satisfied from this module.

**pytz**

> `pytz` brings the Olson `tz` database into Python. This library allows
>   accurate and **cross platform** timezone calculations using Python 2.4
>   or higher. It also solves the issue of ambiguous times at the end
>   of daylight saving time, which you can read more about in the Python
>   Library Reference (`datetime.tzinfo`).

Also I would recommend for reading: [Understanding DateTime, tzinfo, timedelta & TimeZone Conversions in python](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/02/understanding-datetime-tzinfo-timedelta-amp-timezo/)

Comment: the link provides incorrect info e.g., compare how it answers *"How to get two days back/after datetime from now ?"* with [this answer to the related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian sure, anyone can do a mistake, but for understanding its good enough. I feel that SO not for me :(

Comment: pytz is overkill.  It is **very slow** just to import (e.g. 1-2 seconds).  It also adds a 638-file package to your dependencies—just to get a 7-line class.