# Python3 create variable from current hour

Tags: python-3.x, time, raspberry-pi, python-3.4

I'm trying to make a python program that tells my Raspberry Pi to turn on an electronic device for the hours from 4:00AM to 10:00AM. Can someone tell me how to set a variable "hour" to the current value for hour in time?

Comment: here's [code example how to find out whether given time (e.g., '12:00` belongs to the given time interval (e.g., `07:00-22:00`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28553237/4279). As [@Benjamin Maurer said](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28882666/4279), it seems like a `cron` job.

Answer (score 2):

With the [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) library.

```
from datetime import datetime
hour = datetime.now().hour
```

But you might want to try another solution. If you're running Linux on that Rpi (which I assume), you can just use the `cron` daemon. That is responsible for launching script at certain times or intervals.

So you can make a "turn-on" and "turn-off" script and just run those with cron. Here some info about cron:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

You basically just have to edit the crontab (with ´crontab -e´ for your user) and add your scripts. Writing a shell script might even be shorter than a python script (depending on what you want to do).