# Python time comparison at midnight

Tags: python, datetime

I  have  to save the time in `AM` `PM` format.

But i am having trouble in deciding  how to enter midnight time.

Suppose the time is   9PM to 6AM next morning. I  have to divide it into day to day basis . Like this

```
t1 = datetime.datetime.strptime('09:00PM', '%I:%M%p').time()

t2 = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:00AM', '%I:%M%p').time()

t3 = datetime.datetime.strptime('06:00AM', '%I:%M%p').time()
```

Now i want to know whether the t2 should be

`12:00 AM` or `11.59PM`

If i do 12:00AM then i can't compare  if `9pm > 12am` but 11.59 looks odd or may be it is right way

Comment: As far as I know a day is from 12am to 11.59pm

Comment: so  its ok to have 11.59 , i don't know some how 59 figure seems awkward . Buf if thats what people use then its ok with me

Comment: It's either that, or use the date (day) to compare as well

Comment: `12:00AM` is effectively `00:00` of any given day. It's just the common way people record times during the first hour of the day. Perhaps you should use 24-hour clock times internally and just convert them to AM/PM format as necessary for input and output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should always use `00:00` (or `12:00 AM`) to represent midnight.

Using `23:59` (or `11:59 PM`) is problematic for a couple of reasons:

- Precision matters in the comparison.  Is `23:59:01` not before midnight?  What about `23:59:59.9999`?
- Duration calculation will be thrown off by whatever precision you chose.  Consider that `10:00 pm` to midnight is 2 hours, not 1 hour and 59 minutes.

To avoid these problems, you should always treat time intervals as half-open intervals.  That is, the range has an inclusive start, and an exclusive end.  In [interval notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals): `[start, end)`

Now with regard to crossing the midnight boundary:

- When you are comparing times that are associated with a date, you can just compare directly:

  ```
  [2015-01-01T21:00,  2015-01-02T06:00) = 9 hours
   2015-01-01T21:00 < 2015-01-02T06:00
  ```
- When you do not have a date, you can determine duration, but you cannot determine order!

  ```
  [21:00, 06:00) = 9 hours
   21:00 < 06:00  OR  21:00 > 06:00
  ```

  The best you can do is determine whether a time is *between* the points covered by the range.

  ```
  Both 23:00 and 01:00 are in the range [21:00, 06:00)
  21:00 is also in that range, but 06:00 is NOT.
  ```

  Think about a clock.  It's modeled as a circle, not as a straight line.
- To calculate duration of a time-only interval that can cross midnight, use the following pseudocode:

  ```
  if (start <= end)
      duration = end - start
  else
      duration = end - start + 24_hours
  ```

  Or more simply:

  ```
  duration = (end - start + 24_hours) % 24_hours
  ```
- To determine whether a time-only value falls within a time-only interval that can cross midnight, use this pseudocode:

  ```
  if (start <= end)
      is_between = start <= value AND end > value
  else
      is_between = start <= value OR  end > value
  ```

Note that in the above pseudocode, I am referring to the *magnitude* of the values, as compared numerically - not the logical time values which, as said earlier, cannot be compared independently without a reference date.

Also, much of this is covered in my [Date and Time Fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/date-time-fundamentals) course on Pluralsight (towards the very end, in "Working With Ranges").

Comment: About half-open ranges and why midnight should be zero: [E.W. Dijkstra: Why numbering should start at zero](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html). Here's [an implementation in Python of `time_diff()` function that find the duration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28607501/4279) and here's [`in_between()` function](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28553237/4279)

Answer (score 0):

How about making `t1 = 09:00PM`, `t2 = 11.59PM`, `t3 = 12:00AM` and `t4 = 06:00AM`. Then you have definite time ranges per day. Of course, adding the date would make time differences evident as well.