# How to check if the current time is in range in python using time strings?

Tags: python, string, time, window, range

I need a way to find out if current time is in range of time window using time strings. So for example start time would be "0:00" and end time would be "3:15".

I came across this solution, [How to check if the current time is in range in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747974/how-to-check-if-the-current-time-is-in-range-in-python), and it's great but it doesn't use time strings. Is there anything in python that I can pass two time strings to and then check if something is between them? Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: `time.strptime` is your friend, and some other converstions to get it to a `time.time()` format so you can do `if start < time.time() > end` logic.

Comment: related: [python time range validator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28526012/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure which version of Python you're using so I worked it up in python3.

```
import time

old_time = time.strptime('01:00', '%H:%M')
new_time = time.strptime('06:00', '%H:%M')

print(old_time)
print(new_time)

if old_time > new_time:
    print('old time is old')
else:
    print('new is cool')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful method of the **time** module:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

Here is an example of it's usage:

```
import time
new_time = time.strptime("0:00", "%H:%M")
other_time = time.strptime("3:15", "%H%M")

print(new_time > other_time)
print(other_time > new_time)
```