# How to check if a time is within a range with date

Tags: python, datetime

I have found some solution but most of them talks about the current date. What I want is that to check if a current time is within `23:00:00` and `07:00:00` next day. I am facing difficulty because date is also involved into this. So if the current time is `00:00:00` then the date would also change and comparing the time with same day `23:00:00` would give me a faulty result. This is what I have come up with now. Please help me in finding the solution

```
cur_time = dt.strptime('2/9/16 00:00', "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
prev_date = dt.strftime(cur_time.date() - timedelta(days=1), "%m/%d/%y")
same_date = dt.strftime(cur_time.date(), '%m/%d/%y')
dosta = dt.strptime(prev_date + "22:00", "%m/%d/%y%H:%M")
satta = dt.strptime(same_date + "07:00", "%m/%d/%y%H:%M")
if dosta < cur_time < satta:
    tariff = 3
else:
    tariff = 6
print(tariff)
```

This would result the tariff to be 3 but if I change the `cur_time` like this

`cur_time = dt.strptime('2/9/16 23:00', "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")`

this won't yield 3. This would give me 6. Because this is comparing the current time with previous day `00:00` and current day `07:00` and current day `23:00` would obviously be greater.

**Edit 1**

`Input: 2/9/16 06:00:00`

`Output: 3...because 06:00:00 is less than 07:00:00 that same day(2/9/2016) and more than 22:00:00 previous day(2/8/16)`

`Input: 2/9/16 23:00:00`
`Output: 3...because 23:00:00 is more than 22:00:00 that same day(2/9/2016)`

`Input: 2/10/16 00:30:00`
`Output: 3...because 00:30:00 is more than 22:00:00 that previous day(2/9/2016) and less than 07:00:00 same day(2/10/2016)`

`Input: 2/10/16 08:00:00`
`Output: 6...because 08:00:00 is more than 07:00:00 that same day(2/9/2016) and less than 22:00:00 on the same day(2/9/2016)`

**Edit 2**
It is still not working with `timedelta` as pointed out by `@a_guest`.
Here is the code

```
for each in zip(data1, data2):
    # client.write_points(json_body_bill_data)
    cur_time = dt.strptime(each[1]['Start'], "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
    # print(cur_time.date())
    dosta = dt.strptime('2200', '%H%M').time()
    # print(dosta)
    lower = datetime.datetime.combine(cur_time.date(), dosta)
    upper = lower + timedelta(hours=8.5)
    print("lower", lower)
    print("upper", upper)
    print(cur_time, lower < cur_time < upper)
```

This is giving me false if `cur_time` is `00:00:00 9/2/16`

**Edit 3**

The probable answer

```
from datetime import datetime, time
import csv
import os


CSV_FILE_ASCO = os.path.join('..', 'res', 'ASCO_METER.csv')
with open(CSV_FILE_ASCO, 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    data = list(reader)

for each in data:
    # print()
    cur_date = datetime.strptime(each['Start'], "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
    if time(7, 0) <= cur_date.time() < time(22, 0):
        tarrif = 6
    else:
        tarrif = 3
    print(cur_date, end=" ")
    print(tarrif)
```

**Can It be improved further. I bet there has to be a more pythonic way to do it**

Comment: To me, it looks like you have all the code segments you need, but you assemble it the wrong way. The problem is that you subtract one day from the current time, no matter if you have to or not. Can you come up with a possible fix yourself? That's always better than to get an answer made up by someone else...

Comment: What's wrong with using `test = cur_time.date() < datetime.today().date()`?

Comment: I can not use `today()` because `cur_time` is coming from a csv file and I need to compare with the time and date mentioned in the csv file.

Comment: @nostradamus If I don't subtract one day from it then, if the current time is `00:00:00` comparing it with `22:00:00` wouldn't work because it would compare with the same date future `23:00:00` o'clock not the previous date

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant... So you need an if-statement, and depending on it you have to subtract / add something to the current day. If you can add more examples (input --> outcome), I would understand better and could probably provide you with a solution.

Comment: You can just create a `datetime` object representing the lower boundary and then add a `timedelta(hours=7)` object in order to obtain the upper boundary.

Comment: @nostradamus Added some input output cases

Comment: @a_guest I have check that out then..Hope that would do the trick.

Comment: Just to clarify, you want to compare the date you read from a CSV to the current date on the clock, right?

Comment: @DanielHepper No. I want to compare the date and time from the csv with the csv dates and `22:00` and `07:00` time

Comment: I'm confused. The code in **edit 3** prints `2016-02-09 06:00:00 3`. According to **edit 1**, it should be `2016-02-09 06:00:00 6`. You are currently only looking at the hour of each date in the CSV. If you want to compare the dates in the CSV to another date, you obviously need another date in your code.

Comment: @DanielHepper Thanks for mentioning. That was a typo..Changed it

Comment: related [python time range validator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28526012/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the easiest solution would be to get rid of the dates altogether and just compare hour values on their own. If a given time is greater than than 7 AM but less than 11 PM, `tarrif = 3`, else `tarrif = 6`. You can do this using the `datetime` object's `hour` property:

```
from datetime import datetime

cur_date = datetime.strptime('2/9/16 07:00', "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
if 7 <= cur_date.hour < 23:
    tarrif = 3
else:
    tarrif = 6
```

For the sake of exactness, I'm assuming the tarrif changes from 6 to 3 at 7AM on the dot, and back to 6 at 11PM on the dot.

Comment: Thanks your solution looks clean and with little modification it's working too...Posted the code in Edit 3

Comment: You can simplify that by using the `hour` property of `datetime` objects:  `7 <= cur_date.hour < 23`

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the date during compare and check if time is > 23:00 or < 07:00. Check working [fiddle](https://repl.it/Fhb1/0):

```
import datetime
dosta = datetime.datetime.strptime("23:00", '%H:%M')
satta = datetime.datetime.strptime("07:00", '%H:%M')

print dosta.time(), satta.time()

for h in range(0,24):

    h = str(h).zfill(1)
    cur_time = datetime.datetime.strptime('2/9/16 {h}:00'.format(h=h), "%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

    if cur_time.time() > dosta.time() or cur_time.time() < satta.time():
        print "IN RANGE " + h
    else:
        print "OUT OF RANGE " + h
```

Comment: It won't be `or`. It would be `and`. Moreover I can not reject the date. I have to take date and time both. Because till `2/9/16 23:30` comparison has to be done with `2/9/16 22:00` but at `2/10/16 00:00`, comparison can not be done with `2/10/16 22:00`

Comment: Every 'next day' between '00:00 ' and '07:00' it's the same of checking the same day between '00:00 ' and '07:00'