# python time mktime throwing error

Tags: python, datetime, time, pandas, mktime

I am trying to convert a pandas datetime to an epoch using the code below.

```
import time
import pandas as pd

compare_date = pd.datetime.today()+pd.DateOffset(days=-60)
print time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(compare_date, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
```

It's throwing an error

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'mktime'
```

I tried with this code as well

```
t = (2009, 2, 17, 17, 3, 38, 1, 48, 0)
secs = time.mktime( t )
print secs
```

And, it's still throwing the same error. I am using Python version 2.7.5. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have somehow set `time` equal to a `unicode` object in your code, you also cannot pass a `Timestamp` to `strptime` it must be a **string**

```
In [15]: time = u"foo"

In [16]: time.mktime
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b93f36374edc> in <module>()
----> 1 time.mktime

AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'mktime'
```

You need to go through your code and see where you have references to `time`, somewhere you have `time = some_unicode_object`

Not exactly sure what you want at the end but using strftime on the TimeStamp object will be closer:

```
print time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(compare_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())

1422748800.0
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I was reading into a variable named 'time'. Thanks!

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, sorry yes meant strptime.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an explanation of the error (see Padraic Cunningham's answer for that) but rather a shorter way of achieving your ultimate aim.

You appear to be converting `compare_date` to a time tuple. This is a direct way of doing it in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
compare_date = pd.datetime.today()+pd.DateOffset(days=-60)
print compare_date.timetuple()
```

Resulting in:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2015, tm_mon=2, tm_mday=1, tm_hour=1, 
                 tm_min=20, tm_sec=43, tm_wday=6, tm_yday=32, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Comment: Yes, I could get an epoch by doing time.mktime(compare_date.timetuple())

Answer (score 0):

See the explanation of `mktime()` error in @[Padraic Cunningham's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29402424/4279).

1. `pandas.datetime` is `datetime.datetime`. You should use it directly:

   ```
   from datetime import datetime, timedelta

   compare_date = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(60)
   posix_timestamp = (compare_date - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
   ```

   See [Converting datetime.date to UTC timestamp in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8777753/4279)

   If you `compare_date` is not in UTC then you should convert it to UTC first. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279) -- note: `mktime()` may fail!
2. To get the timestamp (epoch time) more directly, you could use `time.time()`:

   ```
   import time

   timestamp = time.time() - 60 * 86400 # 60 days ago
   ```

Both solutions ignore leap seconds (unless "right" timezone is used in the 2nd one).