# How to subtract datenow from time string?

Tags: python, date, datetime, time, web-scraping

I have a problem that seems really easy but I can't figure it out.

**I want to achieve the following:
Time_as_string - time_now = minutes left until time as string.**

I scrape a time from a website as a string, for example: `'15:30'`.

I want to subtract the current time from this to show how many minutes
are left untill the scraped time string.

I tried many things like `strftime()`, converting to unix timestamp, googling solutions etc.
I can make a time object from the string through `strftime()` but I can't subtract it from the current time.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: what about the date?

Comment: local time may be non-monotonous and ambiguous. Convert the time to UTC first if you don't want an hour off errors. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `'15:30'` belongs to today:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
then = datetime.combine(now, datetime.strptime('15:30', '%H:%M').time())
minutes = (then - now) // timedelta(minutes=1)
```

If there could be midnight between now and then i.e., if `then` is tomorrow; you could consider a negative difference (if `then` appears to be in the past relative to `now`) to be an indicator of that:

```
while then < now:
    then += timedelta(days=1)
minutes = (then - now) // timedelta(minutes=1)
```

On older Python version, `(then - now) // timedelta(minutes=1)` doesn't work and you could use `(then - now).total_seconds() // 60` instead.

The code assumes that the utc offset for the local timezone is the same `now` and `then`. See [more details on how to find the difference in the presence of different utc offsets in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: no. `then - now` is correct. Read the question.

Comment: Sorry yes, my mistake , should then = 20:46 -  now = 19:46 not return 60?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I don't understand. What result do you expect in this case instead?

Comment: Scratch that,  I see where the difference is coming between your code and mine.

Comment: Thank you J.F. , after setting the timezone on my server correctly this worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime

s = "15:30"
t1 = datetime.strptime(s,"%H:%M")

diff = t1 - datetime.strptime(datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M"),"%H:%M")

print(diff.total_seconds() / 60)
94.0
```

Comment: `diff.seconds` ignores `diff.days` -- it is relevant for negative differences. Unnecessary `datetime -> str -> datetime` conversions are ugly.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian,  the OP has no dates just times so I presumed all times are before t1, who is to say 15:30 or any other time is not  three weeks before?

Comment: (1) OP wants *"minutes left until time"* i.e., `t1` should be in the future (your answer tries to find the reverse). (2) the negative timedelta is represented as `.days=-1, .seconds=large seconds number`. Use `diff.total_seconds()` instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, yes my mistake. I  had to reverse the logic.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is probably to subtract two datetimes from each other and use `total_seconds()`:

```
>>> d1 = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 20, 00)
>>> d2 = datetime.datetime(2000, 1, 1, 16, 30)
>>> (d1 - d2).total_seconds()
12600.0
```

Note that this won't work if the times are in different timezones (I just picked January 1, 2000 to make it a datetime). Otherwise, construct two datetimes in the same timezones (or UTC), subtract those and use `total_seconds()` again to get the difference (time left) in seconds.