# How do I find the difference between two times in python in a format?

Tags: python, linux, time, difference

I was wondering how can I calculate the time difference between two times which have PM and AM next to them for example. I have 12:16:44 pm and  01:01:45 pm but when I use this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

s1=12:16:44
s2=01:01:45
FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(s2), FMT) - datetime.strptime(s1), FMT)
if tdelta.days < 0:
    tdelta = timedelta(days=0,
                       seconds=tdelta.seconds,
                       microseconds=tdelta.microseconds)
```

but this is the output I get 
 `12:16:44 | 01:01:45 | Time Difference: -1 day, 12:45:01` but they are both PM values? Thanks

Comment: To take into account possible utc offset changes e.g., due to DST transitions, see [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279)

Answer (score 1):

In Python, %H means 24 hour time format. %I is 12 hour format and even then you should specify PM in the string

Try that (and fix syntax errors):

```
s1='12:16:44 PM' 
s2='01:01:45 PM' 
FMT = '%I:%M:%S %p'
```

Comment: Your code is actually invalid. strings should be demilited by quotes. For more on format string check https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html

Comment: So how would I do that?

Comment: s1='12:16:44 PM'
s2='01:01:45 PM'
FMT = '%I:%M:%S %p'

Comment: will this work for am as well so for example s1='09:16:44 am'

Comment: @Dabnas, why don't you try it out?