# Dates subtraction: has the event occurred or not?

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, timedelta

If I have everyday datetime - how to find out, the event has already occurred or not, by subtraction with **datetime.now()**

Let we had everyday meeting at 15:35. Today John came earlier - at 12:45, but Alex was late for 2 h. and 15 min. (came at 17:40).

```
meet_dt = datetime(year=2015, month=8, day=19, hour=15, minute=35)
john_dt = datetime(year=2015, month=8, day=19, hour=12, minute=45)
alex_dt = datetime(year=2015, month=8, day=19, hour=17, minute=40)

print(meat_dt - john_dt) # came before > 2:50:00
print(meat_dt - alex_dt) # came after  > -1 day, 21:55:00
```

If I take away from the big date less - then everything is fine, but conversely I recive **-1 day, 21:55:00** why not **-2:15:00**, what a minus day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Because timedeltas are normalized**

All of the parts of the timedelta other than the days field are always nonnegative, [as described in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta).

Incidentally, if you want to see what happened first, don't do this subtraction.  Just compare directly with `<`:

```
if then < datetime.datetime.now():
    # then is in the past
```

Comment: unrelated: [use `.utcnow()` to handle DST transitions transparently.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I would strongly recommend using `now(timezone.utc)` instead if you want UTC time.