# Django datetime.timedelta , how does its subtract from timezone.now() if they are posssibly different sets

Tags: python, django, datetime

I am having trouble understanding functions that use:

```
time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
```

Firstly the timezone.now() gives the time that is set in Django … now the `datetime.timedelta(days=30)` …

does it use the internal settings in django as set setting.py or another.

Secondly if so … should: the variable time not be 30days behind the current timezone.now();

In the function below

```
def test_was_published_recently_with_old_question(self):
    """
    was_published_recently() should return False for questions whose
    pub_date is older than 1 day.
    """
    time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)
    old_question = Question(pub_date=time)
    self.assertEqual(old_question.was_published_recently(), False)
```

how does this produce 1 day older … I think my issue is not understanding

`time = timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)` in its entirely

I would really appreciate the help. I am new to python and med level programmer … but haven't worked much with time.

Comment: Run `python manage.py shell` and see that `timezone.now()` is a `datetime` object that is expected to work with `timedelta`. Unrelated: make sure  `USE_TZ=True` so that `timezone.now()` returns an aware datetime object otherwise the result of `.was_published_recently()` may be inaccurate, see [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Answer (score 15):

> Firstly the timezone.now() gives the time that is set in Django … now the `datetime.timedelta(days=30)` …
>
> does it use the internal settings in django as set setting.py or another.

First of all `timezone.now()` is just an "improved" version of `datetime.datetime.now()` that's also timezone aware.

```
timezone.now()
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 19, 45, 34, 105121, tzinfo=<UTC>)
datetime.datetime.now()
>>> datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 10, 19, 45, 48, 356860)
```

There is no django internal time. `timezone.now()` is literally just the datetime function + timezone.

---

`timedelta` then is just a difference, a delta as used in physics. It doesn't know anything about time.

When you substract/add a delta from a time you do the according thing to the time.

So today is 2015-09-10. If you add one day (`timedelta(days=1)`) to that that's obviously 2015-09-11.

A check whether something is more recent than a month in python is done by substracting 30 days from now (or 1 month if you like) and then comparing if the saved time is *bigger* than that.

---

To understand the datetime comparison better it may help converting these to unixtime and just seeing these abstract things as simple numbers by using the `timestamp()` function:

```
one_month_ago = (timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)).timestamp()
now = timezone.now().timestamp()
print(one_month_ago)
print(now)
if one_month_ago < now:
    print("a month ago is smaller")
```

outputs

```
1439323463.786164
1441915463.786201
a month ago is smaller
```

Doing this without converting to timestamp prints `a month ago is smaller` too.

Comment: [unless `USE_TZ=True`; `timezone.now()` may return a naive datetime object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/_modules/django/utils/timezone/#now)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confused from the description of the test method.

This test method is testing that `was_published_recently()` works correctly by not returning those questions that are older than 1 day.

To test it, what they are doing is setting a post's date 30 days less than today (that's the `- datetime.timedelta(days=30)`, and then checking if `was_published_today()` is True or False for that post.

If its False, then the test passes.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is my main confusion, I kind of get it... still a bit lost why this function would then return false for post older than a day as stated in the comments... Surely it would be posts older than 30 days as specified by the delta, in light of Christophers answer....