# Python: Compare creation directory time with datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, time

I try to wire a little script in order to find if a directory file was created in the las 24 hours

```
import time

path = /some/path/dir
currentTime = time.strftime("%c")
print currentTime   # Tue Sep 15 18:08:54 2015
if os.path.isdir(path):
    created = time.ctime(os.path.getctime(path)) 
    print created   # Thu Sep 25 17:29:28 2014
    if created > 24 hours: # time don't have comparison  
        # do someting
```

So i trying with "datetime" and .timedelta to perform the maths, but i not able to get the creation time from the directory.

```
import datetime

print datetime.datetime(os.path.getctime(path))
    # AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'datetimep'
```

Thanks for your time :D

Comment: 'module' object has no attribute 'datetimep' < --- 'datetimep'? what's with the p? you may want to look into that.

Comment: Use `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp()` to convert from timestamp to a datetime object.

Comment: Hi @mdurant is working now. thanks :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's one solution

```
if time.mktime(time.localtime()) - os.path.getctime(path) < 24 * 60 * 60:
    ....
```

Comment: Note the change, use localtime just in case your machine isn't UTC.

Comment: `mktime(localtime())` may return a wrong value during DST transitions (with ambiguous local time). [Use `time.time()` instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32597555/4279).

Answer (score 0):

`os.path.getctime(path)` returns "seconds since epoch" (Unix time). To compare it with the current time, use `time.time()`:

```
import os
import time

DAY = 86400 # seconds -- POSIX day
if (time.time() - os.path.getctime(path)) > DAY:
    print("more than 24 hours have passed")
```

`getctime()` returns [the creation time for `path` on Windows but on other systems (Unix) it may return the time of the last metadata change](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.getctime).

See also, [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279).