# Finding difference in time

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I am creating a program in Python in which the user has to type the alphabet as quick as possible and then the computer outputs the time they took. My code so far is:

```
import sys
from datetime import *

ready = raw_input('Press enter when ready')

first = datetime.now().time()
alph = raw_input('TYPE!!!')
second = datetime.now().time()
if alph != 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
    print 'Inocrrect!'
    sys.exit()
else:
    time = second - first
    print 'It took you', time.seconds
```

The programs has an error when working out the difference between the two times:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.time'
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: don't use local time to find the elapsed time, use either UTC time or aware datetime objects. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot subtract `datetime.time` from `datetime.time` objects. It would be better to use `datetime.now()` (which contains both date and time components). Example -

```
first = datetime.now()
alph = raw_input('TYPE!!!')
second = datetime.now()
```

Answer (score 1):

Arithmetic is not supported on Python's `time` type.  Try using just the `datetime` instead:

```
first = datetime.now()
alph = raw_input('TYPE!!!')
second = datetime.now()
```