# working with datetime: get the difference between dates as an integer

Tags: python, date, datetime

```
def work(dat1, dat2):

>>> from datetime import date
>>> work(date(1969, 10, 5), date(1975, 10, 14))

>>> x = dat1 - dat2
>>> return x
datetime.timedelta(2200)
```

How can I simply return the value without 'datetime.timedelta' ? In this case I want to return 2200.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: in general, (if you need more precise result) there could be time zone issues, see [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to get the difference of dates (without time), then retrieving the `days` attribute is enough:

```
(date(1975, 10, 14) - date(1969, 10, 5)).days
```

If you need days with floating point precision then I would calculate this using `total_seconds()` as:

```
(dt1 - dt2).total_seconds() / (3600*24)
```

Comment: Do you mean `(date(...) - date(...))` rather than `(date(...), date(...))`?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for, is the distance in days between the two dates? In that case `return x.days` should do the trick. For more info on timedelta objects, read https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects