# Python add days in epoch time

Tags: python, unix-timestamp, timedelta

How to add days in epoch time in Python

```
#lssec -a lastupdate -s root -f /etc/security/passwd 2>/dev/null | cut -f2 -d=
1425917335
```

above command giving me epoch time I want to add 90 days in that time. how do I add days in epoch time?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) makes it easy between `fromtimestamp`, `timedelta` and `timestamp`:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> orig = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1425917335)
>>> new = orig + datetime.timedelta(days=90)
>>> print(new.timestamp())
1433693335.0
```

On Python 3.2 and earlier, `datetime` objects don't have a `.timestamp()` method, so you must change the last line to the less efficient two-stage conversion:

```
>>> import time
>>> print(time.mktime(new.timetuple()))
```

The two-stage conversion takes ~10x longer than `.timestamp()` on my machine, taking ~2.5 µs, vs. ~270 ns for `.timestamp()`; admittedly still trivial if you aren't doing it much, but if you need to do it a lot, consider it another argument for using modern Python. :-)

Comment: my python 2.6 doesn't have `>>> print(new.timestamp())` function getting error `AttributeError: 'datetime.datetime' object has no attribute 'timestamp'`

Comment: @Satish: Pre-3.3, you can cobble together `.timestamp()` using `time.mktime(x.timetuple())`. It's uglier (and you need to `import time`), but equivalent. Note, you may, depending on source of the timestamp and whether it's using UTC or local time, want to use `utcfromtimestamp`and `utctimetuple` instead of the non-UTC functions given.

Comment: Side-note: 2.6? Really? 2.7 has been out for over five years!

Comment: I have imported both `datetime` and `time` but it didn't work, same error, any other work around?

Comment: @Satish: Wait, what? You couldn't possibly have the same error if you didn't call `.timestamp()`, and my suggestion was to replace `new.timestamp()` with `time.mktime(new.timetuple())`.

Comment: Its works! you are right, i use `print new` and it works

Comment: it may fail if the local timezone may have different utc offset at different dates.

Answer (score 7):

If the input is POSIX timestamp then to get +90 days:

```
DAY = 86400 # POSIX day (exact value)
future_time = epoch_time + 90*DAY
```

If you want to work with datetime objects then use UTC timezone:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

utc_time = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(epoch_time)
future_time = utc_time + timedelta(90)
```

Don't use local time for the date/time arithmetic (avoid  naive `fromtimestamp()`, `mktime()`, `naive_dt.timestamp()` if you can help it). To understand when it may fail, read [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279).

Answer (score 0):

You can you dateutil.parser as well:

```
since24Hours = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=1)
since24Hours=dateutil.parser.parse(str(since24Hours))
since24Hours = since24Hours.strftime('%s')
since24Hours=int(since24Hours)*1000
```