# Set now as minimum datetime in Python 3.4

Tags: python, datetime, tkinter, python-datetime

I am currently developing an application in which a user fills out forms to submit upcoming activities (which will later be automatically scheduled, haven't got to that yet). So far I have been using the standard `datetime` module for validation on form inputs to check that valid datetimes are being inputed, for example:

```
import datetime
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as tkMessageBox

#Loads of tkinter stuff leading to variables year, month, day, hour, minute

try:
    start_date_time = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)
except ValueError as inst:
    tkMessageBox.showerror("Invalid input",inst)
```

This has been very successful. My problem now is that I want to validate that `start_date_time` is in the future. I was hoping that I would be able to do this by manipulating `datetime.datetime.min` and `datetime.datetime.max` in order to make the existing code validate to see if an input is in the future (and not unreasonably far in the future, too).

This is how I have tried to achieve this:

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.datetime.min = now
```

But this raises the following `TypeError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "J:\COMP4 Project\GUI.py", line 13, in <module>
    datetime.datetime.min = now
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'datetime.datetime'
```

**My question is:** Is there a work around so that the values of `datetime.datetime.min` and `datetime.datetime.max` can be changed or must I write code to check each datetime to be validated is greater than `now`?

Comment: Seriously, what's the problem with `start_date_time > now`?

Comment: @karlson Nothing is _wrong_ as such with that, I want to know if there is a work around so that I don't have to write loads of lines of `start_date_time > now`, as in the actual application there are loads of situations where I need to do this.

Comment: @R.Murray, well, you always can set up a variable like this: `data_ok=start_date_time>now` and then check whether it's true or not: `if data_ok: print "great!"`

Comment: No, you can't do that, but you could write a `validate_date` function and keep that logic in there.

Comment: And what would you gain from monkey patching `datetime.min` and `datetime.max`? This won't make you happy. Write functions to not repeat yourself.

Comment: I appreciate this might not be the right thing to do, I was just asking. BUT is it _possible_? @karlson

Comment: "If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea." - [PEP-20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always subclass `datetime.datetime` and implement the check yourself:

```
import datetime

class MyDatetime(datetime.datetime):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        if self < datetime.datetime.now():
            raise ValueError("Date must be in the future")

MyDatetime(2017,10,10)  # Ok

MyDatetime(2010,10,10)  # Not ok
```

But seriously, don't do this. Just check `start_date_time > now` in a validation function, as you have written in your own answer.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't thought of that. However, I do agree with the last sentence!

Answer (score 2):

Until I hear otherwise, setting the value of `datetime.datetime.min` and `datetime.datetime.max` is not possible, though `datetime.MINYEAR` and `datetime.MAXYEAR` can be changed, which then affects `datetime.datetime.min` and `datetime.datetime.max`. The best way to carry out validation on `datetime` objects, such that a check is carried out to check an activity is in the future taking in to account months, days, hours and minutes, in my situation is by using a function. For example:

```
def validateFuture(x):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    if x > now:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

(where x is a `datetime.datetime` object such as start_date_time from the question)

Comment: this code may break during DST transitions (local time may jump back). See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26313848/4279)