# Python difference between two dates with time module

Tags: python, time

Is there a way to do time difference with time and not datetime, this is what I would liek to do:

```
date1 = time.strptime('02/03/2016 16:01:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
date2 = time.localtime(time.time())
print date2 - date1
```

But I am getting only the error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'time.struct_time' and 'time.struct_time'
```

Comment: So the error is saying that you can't do simple subtraction of time objects. Can you do something like time.difference(date2, date1)? ps I have no python exp.

Comment: Why doesn't `datetime` work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `time.mktime()` to get the number of seconds since the epoch from a `time_struct`:

```
date = time.strptime('02/03/2016 16:01:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
seconds_since_epoch = time.mktime(date)
difference = time.time() - seconds_since_epoch
print time.local_time(difference)
```

Comment: What about subtracting two time_struct objects, as the OP asked?

Comment: @RafaelCardoso I don't understand... you can't do that. The OP is asking for the difference between two `time_struct`s, which is exactly what this is

Comment: It should be `print time.localtime(difference)`

Comment: @Dominik: `time.mktime()` may fail. If you need reliable results; use `pytz`. See related question: [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>>
>>>
>>> d1 = datetime.strptime('02/03/2016 16:01:55', '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
>>> d1
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 2, 16, 1, 55)
>>> d2 = datetime.now()
>>> d1
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 2, 16, 1, 55)
>>> d2
datetime.datetime(2016, 3, 3, 18, 7, 14, 931872)
>>> d2 - d1
datetime.timedelta(1, 7519, 931872)
>>> (d2 - d1).seconds
7519
>>> (d2 - d1).days
1
```