# Subtracting two time moments specified as strings

Tags: python, datetime

I have one datetime object

`2016-04-11 19:46:46-04:00`

and

`2016-04-25 09:35:18.464966` (this one is `datetime.datetime.now()`)

How do I get them to the same format so I can subtract them?

Comment: What does the `-04:00` at the end mean?

Comment: `datetime.strptime` if those are both strings to get them into a `datetime` object to be subtracted

Comment: I think it's a way of off setting time zone? The original dictionary looks like this {"name": "Date",
      "value": "Mon, 11 Apr 2016 19:46:46 -0400"}

Comment: Yes, it's a timezone offset, but `-04:00` is not the correct representation of that

Comment: can you put this in an answer so I can mark it as answered? Thank you.

Comment: If they're both `datatime` objects, can't you just subtract them and get a [`timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html?highlight=timedelta#datetime.timedelta) object?

Comment: related: [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dateutil.parser`.

```
from dateutil.parser import *
import datetime

date1="2016-04-11 19:46:46-04:00"
date2=datetime.datetime.now()
updated_date1=parse(date1, ignoretz=True) #Ignoring TimeZone
updated_date2=parse(str(date2))
result=updated_date2 - updated_date1
print result
```

Comment: it is wrong if the current utc offset is not `-04:00` (e.g., if there was a DST transition between now and then or if the local timezone is different). Don't ignore the timezone information. Convert `date1` to utc (`date1.replace(tzinfo=None) - date1.utcoffset()`) and use `.utcnow()` instead of `.now()`, to find the time difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your first date string has a time zone and `datetime.datetime.now()` is timezone free.

You can parse the first string like so:

```
>>> d1=datetime.datetime.strptime("2016-04-11 19:46:46-0400", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
>>> print(d1)
2016-04-11 19:46:46-04:00
```

Or, if you have the `:` in the time zone offset, you need to remove it with a regex or partition:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime(''.join('2016-04-11 19:46:46-04:00'.rpartition(':')[0::2]), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 11, 19, 46, 46, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 72000)))
```

Note that I have done this in Python 3 since Python prior to 3.2 is [spotty](http://bugs.python.org/issue6641) supporting the `%z` directive. (It is only supported if the C library used to build Python supports it. Python 3.2 and later has native support.)

Now to compare or add/subtract you either need to add a timezone to `datetime.datetime.now()` or remove it from `d1`. Here is how to remove it:

```
>>> d1.replace(tzinfo=None)
datetime.datetime(2016, 4, 11, 19, 46, 46)
```

Then you can subtract:

```
>>> d1.replace(tzinfo=None)-datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.timedelta(-14, 42738, 274649)
```

If you want to make the timezone free time the same timezone, you can do:

```
>>> d1-datetime.datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=d1.tzinfo)
datetime.timedelta(-14, 41899, 435274)
```

Answer (score 0):

> The original dictionary looks like this {"name": "Date", "value": "Mon, 11 Apr 2016 19:46:46 -0400"}
>   ...
>   this one is `datetime.datetime.now()`

To find elapsed seconds since the given time (specified as a **string**):

```
import time
from email.utils import parsedate_tz, mktime_tz

d = {"name": "Date", "value": "Mon, 11 Apr 2016 19:46:46 -0400"}
then = mktime_tz(parsedate_tz(d['value']))
now = time.time()
elapsed_seconds = now - then
```

Don't confuse `datetime` **objects** (`type(obj) == datetime.datetime`) and strings (`type(obj) == str`).