# Remove time from timedelta output in python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I've written a small python script to determine the age of a record and if it is more than a week old.  I do this by subtracting the record date from `now()`.  The record returns the date `2016-02-23 09:01:22` as datetime.

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
age = now - recordDate
print age
```

this prints the result as `71 days, 23:56:07.156000`

Is there a more "pythonic" way to get it to output just the days (and no hours etc.) than my hack solution of

```
print str(age).split(',',1)[0]
```

which prints the result as `71 days`?

Comment: unrelated: the local time may be non-linear. Don't use `datetime.now()` if you want to find the exact difference. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279). If you don't care about hours in your case; use `date.today()` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`71 days, 23:56:07.156000` is a *string representation* of the [`timedelta` object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

To get the days only, just get the, well, `.days`:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> 
>>> recordDate = datetime(year=2010, month=10, day=10)
>>> now = datetime.now()
>>> age = now - recordDate
>>> age  # age is the timedelta object
datetime.timedelta(2033, 61630, 853029)
>>> "%d days" % age.days
'2033 days'
```