# compare datetime.now() with utc timestamp with python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a timestamp such `1474398821633L` that I think is in utc. I want to compare it to datetime.datetime.now() to verify if it is expired.

I am using python 2.7

```
from datetime import datetime

timestamp = 1474398821633L
now = datetime.now()

if datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp) < now:
    print "timestamp expired"
```

However I got this error when trying to create a datetime object from the timestamp: `ValueError: timestamp out of range for platform localtime()/gmtime() function`

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@mgilson pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39602250/4279) your input is likely "milliseconds", not "seconds since epoch".

Use `time.time()` instead of `datetime.now()`:

```
import time

if time.time() > (timestamp_in_millis * 1e-3):
    print("expired")
```

If you need `datetime` then use `datetime.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.now()`. Do not compare `.now()` that returns local time as a naive datetime object with `utcfromtimestamp()` that returns UTC time also as a naive datetime object (it is like comparing celsius and fahrenheit directly: you should convert to the same unit first).

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.utcnow()
then = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(timestamp_in_millis * 1e-3)
if now > then:
    print("expired")
```

See more details in [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279).

Answer (score 4):

It *looks* like your timestamp is in milliseconds.  Python uses timestamps in seconds:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(1474398821.633)
datetime.datetime(2016, 9, 20, 19, 13, 41, 633000)
```

In other words, you might need to divide your timestamp by `1000.` in order to get it in the proper range.

Also, you'll probably want to compare `datetime.utcnow()` instead of `datetime.now()` to make sure that you're handling timezones correctly :-).

Comment: @BelowtheRadar -- I guessed :-).  Some other languages that I know of tend to work in milliseconds (e.g. Javascript), so it seemed natural that you could have a timestamp out of range if it was a milliseconds timestamp rather than a seconds timestamp.

Comment: it is not enough to interpret it as milliseconds. OP should use UTC time instead of the local time returned by `datetime.now()`.