# Open files older than 3 days of date stamp in file name - Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, datestamp

** Problem **
I'm trying to open (in python) files older than 3 days of the date stamp which is in the current name. Example: 2016_08_18_23_10_00 - JPN - MLB - Mickeymouse v Burgerface.ply. So far I can create a date variable, however I do not know how to search for this variable in a filename. I presume I need to convert it to a string first?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import os
import re
path = "C:\Users\michael.lawton\Desktop\Housekeeper"

## create variable d where current date time is subtracted by 3 days ##

days_to_subtract = 3
d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)

print d

## open file in dir where date in filename = d or older ##

for filename in os.listdir(path):
if re.match(d, filename):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as f:
        print line,
```

Any help will be much appreciated

Comment: Side-note: Use raw strings for Windows paths (and regular expressions for that matter). It didn't bite you this time (you got lucky), but it will, eventually, when you have a path where a file or directory in it has a name starting with, for example `b`, `f`, `n`, etc. (getting you embedded backspace, form feed or newline, respectively). Just put an `r` in front of the literal (and don't end it with a backslash), e.g. `path = r"C:\Users\michael.lawton\Desktop\Housekeeper"` and this can't happen by accident.

Comment: Thanks for that, duly noted!

Comment: if you want to open files that are 3 days older and not a minute younger then you have to take into account the local timezone. See [Find if 24 hrs have passed between datetimes - Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26313520/4279)

Comment: @ShadowRanger: a nitpick: there are no "raw strings" in memory there are only "raw string literals" in the source code. Otherwise, it is a good recomendation to use `r''` for Windows paths (to avoid escaping the backslashes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strptime` for this. It will convert your string (assuming it is correctly formatted) into a datetime object which you can use to compare if your file is older than 3 days based on the filename:

```
from datetime import datetime

...

lines = []
for filename in os.listdir(path):
  date_filename = datetime.strptime(filename.split(" ")[0], '%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
  if date_filename < datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_subtract):
    with open(os.path.join(path, filename), 'r') as f:
      lines.extend(f.readlines()) # put all lines into array
```

If the filename is `2016_08_18_23_10_00 - JPN - MLB - Mickeymouse v Burgerface.ply` the datetime part will be extracted with `filename.split(" ")[0]`. Then we can use that to check if it is older than three days using `datetime.timedelta`

Comment: Thanks. What is the integer division for at the end? `// open file`

Comment: Sorry that is soppused to be a comment, I'm used to coding in C where // means a comment :)

Comment: Can't read the file, need buffer, however I don't understand buffer, could you explain? TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, datetime.datetime found
>>>

Comment: `for filename in os.listdir(path):
  date_filename = datetime.datetime.strptime(filename.split(" ")[0], '%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')
if date_filename < datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_subtract):
                     #this works#
              file = open(date_filename,'r')
                       print file.read()`

Comment: You are trying to read from the `date_filename` variable (which is a datetime object) you really wanna read from the filename variable (see my edited answer).

Comment: Ah, thank you, I see it now, silly mistake. I have one issue left which I don't understand at all - ValueError: mode string must begin with one of 'r', 'w', 'a' or 'U'. `str(filename) 
                       file = open(path,filename)
                       print file.read()`

Comment: Got it, I used os.path.join(path,filename)) Thank you for all your help!

Comment: @user6705306 glad to help. Please mark my answer as the best answer if it solved your problem. That way others can know your problem was solved.

Comment: Cheers and marked. I've ran into one more problem. As I don't understand this fully yet but need to solve this quickly - How enter all files with the naming convention that meets the `datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=days_to_subt‌​ract)` into the variable `filename` within the 'path' ?

Comment: @user6705306 Do you want to put all the matching files into an array?

Comment: @user6705306 see my edited answer. It adds all the lines to a single array using [extend](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_extend.htm). If you need any more help I advice putting up a new question appropriate for that.

Answer (score 0):

To open all files in the given directory that contain a timestamp in their name older than 3 days:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
import time

DAY = 86400 # POSIX day in seconds
three_days_ago = time.time() - 3 * DAY
for filename in os.listdir(dirpath):
    time_string = filename.partition(" ")[0]
    try:
        timestamp = time.mktime(time.strptime(time_string, '%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S'))
    except Exception: # can't get timestamp
        continue
    if timestamp < three_days_ago: # old enough to open
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as file: # assume it is a file
            for line in file:
                print line,
```

The code assumes that the timestamps are in the local timezone. It may take DST transitions into account on platforms where C `mktime()` has access to [the tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) (if it doesn't matter whether the file is 72  or 73 hours old in your case then just ignore this paragraph).

Consider using file metadata such as "the last modification time of a file" instead of extracting the timestamp from its name: `timestamp = os.path.getmtime(path)`.

Comment: Thank you both. I have gone with the first answer due to date stamps and date modified's being different. Really appreciate the help.